# Does setting autocommit=0 within a transaction do anything?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I am reviewing code by another developer. He has a commit that explicitly adds `set autocommit=0` at the start of a MySQL transaction. This is causing problems for other non-transactional queries in the session.

Does adding `set autocommit=0` within a transaction do anything for *that* transaction? I assume it doesn't, since transactions implicitly do this anyway.

[The only rationale I can come up with for this commit is perhaps the db once used MyISAM (versus the current InnoDB), and this was maybe a way to mimic transactions in the former?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a transaction is active, it is not affected by `SET autocommit = 0`.

Otherwise, if the former value of `autocommit` was `1`, `SET autocommit = 0` starts a new transaction.

If you are using MariaDB and you are in doubt, you can check the `in_transaction` variable.

Comment: The code is as follows: `START TRANSACTION; SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ; SET autocommit = 0; [some queries]  COMMIT;` What is the point of the `SET autocommit = 0` in this?

Comment: No purpose. Also, the isolation level cannot be changed during the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html):

> After disabling autocommit mode by setting the autocommit variable to
>   zero, changes to transaction-safe tables (such as those for InnoDB or
>   NDB) are not made permanent immediately. You must use COMMIT to store
>   your changes to disk or ROLLBACK to ignore the changes.

Setting `autocommit=0` will modify the entire session.
Transactions and non-transactional commands will need to explictly committed to affect the DB.

Comment: Right, but you have to do explicit commits (or start a new transaction) for transactions anyway. So, in regards to transactions, what effect does disabling autocommit have?