# How to check if we are in the middle of transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

What is the proper way to check if we are in the middle of transaction in MySQL ?

I guess that using `SELECT @@autocommit;` is not the way to go ?

also something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX WHERE TRX_MYSQL_THREAD_ID = CONNECTION_ID();
```

found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31231025/3402095), didn't work.

Comment: Try this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620966/mysql-5-5-getting-the-current-transaction-id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually no luck. Which example did you actually had in mind?

Comment: One possible option to evaluate is: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36840813](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36840813). `SET TRANSACTION without GLOBAL or SESSION is not permitted while there is an active transaction:`, see [13.3.6 SET TRANSACTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html).

Comment: I recommend you clean up the app code so that the question has an obvious answer.